# Inverse element of a magma

Tags: abstract-algebra, magma, quasigroups

It is accepted that two elements are inverse to each other if their product is equal to the identity element:
[Inverse element in a magma](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3513372/427611)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_element

The definition works fine for associative structures.
But let us take a closer look at non-associative case.
What do we mean by inverse element?
Intuitively, it is an element that reverses the action of a given element.
And what is the action of an element?
The most appropriate definition of an action of an element $a$ onto a magma $A(\cdot)$ is its translation $a \cdot A$ or $A \cdot a$.
But then the inverse action should be defined as $(a \cdot A)^{-1}$ or $(A \cdot a)^{-1}$.
In other words, a left inverse element of an element $x$ is an element $y$ such that $y \cdot A = (x \cdot A)^{-1}$.
A right inverse element of an element $x$ is an element $y$ such that $A \cdot y = (A \cdot x)^{-1}$.

On element level the definitions can be written as:

- $y$ is a left inverse element of $x$ if $y \cdot (x \cdot a) = x \cdot (y \cdot a) = a$ for any element $a$ of $A(\cdot)$.
- $y$ is a right inverse element of $x$ if $(a \cdot x) \cdot y = (a \cdot y) \cdot x = a$ for any element $a$ of $A(\cdot)$.

Obviously, in order for the inverse translations $(a \cdot A)^{-1}$ or $(A \cdot a)^{-1}$ to exist,
the actions $a \cdot A$ or $A \cdot a$ must be permutations.

These definitions look more consistent and do not require existence of the identity element,
similar to how the definition of an inverse function does not require existence of an identity function.

For example, all elements are inverse to themselves in the following quasigroup:

$$ \begin{array}{c|ccc} \cdot & a & b & c \\ \hline a & a & c & b \\ b & c & b & a \\ c & b & a & c \end{array}$$

Indeed, each element of the magma reverses its own action:
$a \cdot (a \cdot a) = a$, $a \cdot (a \cdot b) = b$, $a \cdot (a \cdot c) = c$, etc.

For associative structures the definitions coincide:
$y \cdot (x \cdot a) = (y \cdot x) \cdot a = a$ for any element $a$ if and only if $y \cdot x = e$.

The new definitions establish the same connection between the inverse operations (divisions) and the inverse elements in a quasigroup as in a group:

An element $x^{-1}$ of a quasigroup is a left (right) inverse of an element $x$ if an only if for any element $a$ of the quasigroup

- $x \backslash a = x^{-1} \cdot a$  (for the left inverse)
- $a / x = a \cdot x^{-1}$ (for the right inverse)

where $\backslash$ and $/$ are the left and the right inverse operations respectively.

Does it make sense to switch to the new definitions for all algebraic structures?

Comment: I don't understand your second question: since the definitions coincide under associativity (as you observe), isn't extension trivial?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I wanted somebody to confirm the statement. Also, I thought there may be some other reasons for choosing one definition over another.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that in the absence of associativity or other assumptions, merely "having inverses" is not a very strong property. That said, the existing definitions and terminology are fine. In loop theory (loop = quasigroup with an identity element), we often want to keep track of left and right inverses of elements even in cases where the left and right division operations $\backslash$ and $/$ cannot be directly expressed in terms of the inverses and the multiplication as in the original post. For example, there are interesting classes of loops with two-sided inverses which happen to satisfy the antiautomorphic inverse property $(xy)^{-1} = y^{-1} x^{-1}$, even though they do not satisfy the left inverse property $x^{-1}y=x\backslash y$ or the right inverse property $xy^{-1}=x/y$. (And yes, those are the standard names for those properties.) There are many other variations on this theme. In short, in loop theory, the usual definitions of left and right inverses are both adequate and useful.